# Sublime Text enter space after autocomplete

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

How would I write a custom key binding or plugin for HTML language that would add `enter` after the tag?

**Example**

Currently Sublime Text does this upon auto complete

```
<table></table>
```

I would like to have this

```
<table>

</table>
```

I hope you guys can help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These snippet-completions are hard coded in the HTML package.

I think the easiest way to archive this, is to write a simple plugin on your own. To do this open your `User` folder (or an other subfolder of Packages) and create a python file (e.g. `html_complete_tag.py`).

Then open the python file and just paste the following code:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
class HtmlCompleteTagCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        view.run_command("commit_completion")
        for sel in view.sel():
            if not sel.empty(): continue
            pos = sel.begin()
            # check we are inside a tag
            if view.substr(sublime.Region(pos-1, pos+1)) == "><":
                # we have: <tag>|<tag/>
                # insert \n< one position after the cursor
                # => <tag>|<\n<tag/>
                view.insert(edit, pos+1, "\n<")
                # remove the char after the cursor
                # => <tag>|\n<tag/>
                view.replace(edit, sublime.Region(pos, pos+1), "")
                # insert a newline and a tab at the cursor
                # => <tag>\n\t|\n<tag/>
                view.insert(edit, pos, "\n\t")
```

This will commit the completion and if inside a tag insert the newlines. The actions are a little bit weird, because we want the cursor to be at the desired position after inserting `\n\t\n`.

To use the keybinding in html just add the following lines to your keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "html_complete_tag", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html" }
    ]
},
```

If you confirm the autocompletion with `enter`, then replace `tab` by `enter` or keep both keybindings.

Comment: Hi @r-stein, I have created the `html_complete_tag.py` and placed it in the `User` directory and also placed the keybindings in the `Preferences > Key Bindings - User` and I have opened a html file I was working on and it doesn't seem to work? :/ Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: If you confirm your autocompletion with the `enter` key, you must change the keybinding from `"keys": ["tab"]` to `"keys": ["enter"]`.